# Change default binaries for texlive

Tags: 11.10, installation, bash, latex, bashrc

Ubuntu ships with texlive 2009, which installs the tex binaries into `/usr/bin/latex`

I've installed the [current version of texlive with its installer](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html), which installs its binaries into `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/`.  I've added it to my path (along with the man and info pages, using my `.bashrc`:

```
MANPATH=$MANPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/man
export MANPATH
INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/info
export INFOPATH
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux
export PATH
```

But latex, tex, etc still run the old versions; `which latex` returns `/usr/bin/latex`.  What is the recommended way to get my system to default to the new binaries, man files, etc?  (Seems this should be possible without remapping each binary by hand or replacing the old ones?)  Many thanks.

Comment: On a side note, environment variables should be set in `.profile` or `.pam_environment`. If you set them in `.bashrc`, they will only apply to commands run from interactive bash shells.

Comment: Thanks.  I assume the syntax is the same?

Comment: in `.profile`, yes. `.pam_environment` is read by the pam-env module, and only accepts `KEY=VALUE` pairs, thus you can't append to PATH via this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will look for thing in the order specified in the path, you've added the new path to the end, and that's why your still getting the old one

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux:$PATH
```

is what your looking for

## update

here's a example

```
$ which ls
/opt/local/libexec/gnubin/ls
$ export PATH=/bin:$PATH
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```